# Cannot find module 'jquery.tagsinput-revisited

Tags: npm, laravel-mix, jquery-tags-input

I've installed *jquery.tagsinput-revisited* via npm, which was provided [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.tagsinput-revisited)

> npm i jquery.tagsinput-revisited

Then, I've added

`require('jquery.tagsinput-revisited');`

in one of my js file and

`@import '~jquery.tagsinput-revisited/src/jquery.tagsinput-revisited';`

in one of SCSS file.

Now, I'm having these error while npm run watch

> This dependency was not found:
>
> - jquery.tagsinput-revisited in ./resources/js/bundle1.js
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save
>   jquery.tagsinput-revisited
>
> ERROR in ./resources/js/bundle1.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'jquery.tagsinput-revisited' in
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\vetforum\www\resources\js'  @
>   ./resources/js/bundle1.js 9:0-37  @ multi ./resources/js/bundle1.js

SCSS file get successfully compiled,but there seems an error in the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, i've done like this

In JS file

```
require('../vendors/tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput-revisited');
```

In SCSS file

```
@import '../vendors/tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput-revisited';
```